# Determining the second derivative based on a sequence of points

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Say $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a $C^2$ function and $x_n \to 0$ is a strictly decreasing sequence. Can we determine $f''(0)$ just from knowing $f(x_n)$?

Comment: Do you mean if $g \in C^2(\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R})$ and $g(x_n) = f(x_n)$, then $g''(0) = f''(0)$?

Comment: If WLOG $f'(0)=0$, you can show that $\frac{f(x_{n}) - f(0)}{2x_{n} ^2}$ converges to $f''(0)$

Comment: @0XLR, yes, that.